# Disable close and minimize option

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Am a beginner to javascript, i have a doubt on this following :-

How to disable print popup window close button and minimize.Am working on a web application using java script.

As we all know print function will show a popup and it has a minimize and close button by default.

Is there any way to disable minimize and close button programmatically.

Is there exist any javascript method to do this?

```
myWindow.print();
```

Thanks,
Please help.

Comment: There's no way to do this with JS.

Comment: Please upvote this question,am a beginner in stack overflow and javascript, i could not post questions anymore ,which is really important for me.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is not worth of voting up. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I have edited the question with more relevant codes i hope, have a look please.Thanks

Comment: Umh... you've invalidated the accepted answer. This is totally new, different question now. This is something we're not supposed to do, ever. I've rolled back to the original question. I took a short view to your questions. Looks like your total question score is positive. Maybe you've deleted a bunch of your questions. I'd advice to improve and reopen some of those. Also questions with score of zero might be easier to edit to fit the rules. I doubt this particular question is salvageable. Notice, that an edited post rises up in the "Active" page, so it will get some attention.

Comment: Actually the updated question was my original functionality i was doing, but i have posted only a part of it at the beginning that was really happened, what i have done later is  posted the entire issue , but may be it invalidated the accepted answer.Let me reopen the deleted questions if any.Anyways thank you so much for helping me to solve my issue.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this? Even if it were possible, I wouldn't have thought anyone sane would give you an answer...

Comment: @ Beta Decay i know , but i have already asked this question already and i got so many down votes.How can i remove the down votes for god sake please find me a way.If i delete this question again my account will be deactivated.

Comment: Please someone up vote this question to remove the negative votes please , i have edited this and the question is clear and solved now.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'print' window is created by your browser, not by Javascript (Javascript just says 'hi browser, could you print this for me?). Luckily, browsers do not allow the 'close' and 'minimize' button to be disabled, as this would create a **VERY** unfriendly user experience (just imagine sites that 'force' you to print a million pages for them). So, there's no 'how to' answer to your question, and that makes the world a better place.

Comment: Thank you so much  for the help.Could you please upvote this question?Am a beginner in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I think print page help user to print it, so you take them to print page instead of minimizing it.. It will automatically go to print page..

```
function PrintWindow()
        {                     
           window.print();            
           CheckWindowState(); 
        }

        function CheckWindowState()
        {            
            if(document.readyState=="complete")
            {
                window.close();  //you can edit it as you want
            }
            else
            {            
                setTimeout("CheckWindowState()", 2000);
            }
        }    

       PrintWindow();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.